# Why does importing a dotted module name fail when upper level is matched by a module in current directory?

Tags: python, import

I was trying out one of the Python standard library modules, let's call it `foo.bar.baz`.

So I wrote a little script starting with

```
import foo.bar.baz
```

and saved it as `foo.py`.

When I executed the script I got an ImportError.  It took me a while (I'm still learning Python), but I finally realized the problem was how I named the script.  Once I renamed `foo.py` to something else, the problem went away.

So I understand that the `import foo` statement will look for the script `foo.py` before looking for the standard library `foo`, but it's not clear to me what it was looking for when I said `import foo.bar.baz`.  Is there some way that `foo.py` could have the content for that statement to make sense?  And if not, why didn't the Python interpreter move on to look for a directory hierarchy like `foo/bar` with the appropriate `__init__.py`'s?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An import statement like `import foo.bar.baz` first imports `foo`, then asks it for `bar`, and then asks `foo.bar` for `baz`. Whether `foo` will, once imported, be able to satisfy the request for `bar` or `bar.baz` is unimportant to the import of `foo`. It's just a module. There is only one `foo` module. Both `import foo` and `import foo.bar.baz` will find the same module -- just like any other way of importing the `foo` module.

There is actually a way for `foo` to be a single module, rather than a package, and still be able to satisfy a statement like `import foo.bar.baz`: it can add `"foo.bar"` and `"foo.bar.baz"` to the `sys.modules` dict. This is exactly what the `os` module does with `os.path`: it imports the right "path" module for the platform (`posixpath`, `ntpath`, `os2path`, etc), and assigns it to the `path` attribute. Then it does `sys.modules["os.path"] = path` to make that module importable as `os.path`, so a statement like `import os.path` works. There isn't really a reason to do this -- `os.path` is available without importing it as well -- but it's possible.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, and good motivation to read up on the whole import process.  When you say the import statement [asks foo] to import bar, are you using the word 'ask' loosely, or is there some method that is called?

Comment: I already changed the wording because I realized that was probably going to be taken too literally :) The `__import__` function does all the actual importing, but it does import `foo` first, then it re-starts the entire import procedure for `foo.bar` -- which means that (among other things) it looks in `sys.modules['foo.bar']` and examines `sys.modules['foo'].__path__`.